# C++ class to access bytes/words of an unsigned integer

Tags: c++, low-level

```
union LowLevelNumber
{
 unsigned int n;
 struct
 {
  unsigned int lowByte : 8;
  unsigned int highByte : 8;
  unsigned int upperLowByte : 8;
  unsigned int upperHighByte : 8;
 } bytes;
 struct
 {
  unsigned int lowWord : 16;
  unsigned int highWord : 16;
 } words;     
};
```

This union allows me to access the unsigned integer byte or word-wise.
However, the code looks rather ugly:

```
var.words.lowWord = 0x66;
```

Is there a way which would allow me to write code like this:

```
var.lowWord = 0x66;
```

Update:
This is really about writing short / beautiful code as in the example above. The union solution itself does work, I just don't want to write .words or .bytes everytime I access lowWord or lowByte.

Comment: You are relying on implementation-defined behavior w.r.t. order of bit-fields and representation of integers in a union. This will break when endianness changes, and maybe even between different compilers. See C99 draft 6.7.2.1 #9 and 6.5.2.3 #5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
union LowLevelNumber {
    unsigned int n;
    struct {
        unsigned int lowByte : 8;
        unsigned int highByte : 8;
        unsigned int upperLowByte : 8;
        unsigned int upperHighByte : 8;
    };
    struct {
        unsigned int lowWord : 16;
        unsigned int highWord : 16;
    };
};
```

Note the removed `bytes` and `words` names.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not that I mind property emulation approach, but I didn't expect you to fall for one given the question you asked and the answers you've been given. ;-)

I have the feeling someone will come and suggest that you use java instead ;-)

Comment: I think you should use Java instead.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm afraid after behrooz' answer you're a bit late ;-)

Answer (score 2):

C++

Would http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/ serve for your needs?

Plain C version would look something like this:

```
int32 foo;

//...

//Set to 0x66 at the low byte
foo &= 0xffffff00;
foo |= 0x66;
```

This is probably going to be more maintainable down the road than writing a custom class/union, because it follows the typical C idiom.

Comment: It's an improvement because the next guy to read your code(or you in 2 years) isn't going to scratch his head wondering what in the world is going on, and have to hunt around for the union code...oh...and your code might brutally fail on a 64-bit machine, too.

Comment: I'd even say that foo.LowByte = 0x66 is more readable than your code. It will only fail on 64 bit machine if the compiler model is not LLP.

Comment: Ah, so your solution requires fiddlyness to make work in the future. My solution won't, plus it is C idiom. Best of luck.

Comment: what I said above is not correct - the union will only fail for an architecture which has a different endianess, because in case of 64 bit integers, the higher bits just aren't affected by the union.
For a different endianess though it will fail and so will your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can make

```
short& loword() { return (short&)(*(void*)&m_source); }
```

and use it if you don't care parenthesis.

Or you can go fancy

```
public class lowordaccess
{
   unsigned int m_source;
public:
   void assign(unsigned int& source) { m_source = source; }
   short& operator=(short& value) { ... set m_source }
   operator short() { return m_source & 0xFF; }
}
```

and then

```
struct LowLevelNumber
{
   LowLevelNumber() { loword.assign(number); }

   unsigned int number;
   lowordaccess loword;
}
var.loword = 1;
short n = var.loword;
```

The latter technique is a known property emulation in C++.

Comment: I really like your approach! very nice

Comment: While I appreciate this, and the code that I present is kind of cool and can be useful in other situations, I didn't really test it, and I personally think that hacker's approach is much more simplier and fits better with the very problem.

Comment: And my code have side effects, like, there're problems doing &var.loword, etc.

Comment: And by the way you could just do "{ MyNumberCtor() { loword = *(short*)((char*)&n + 1); } short& loword; }" i.e. have reference field named loword. You don't really need go fancy ;-)

Comment: Although I upvoted the last comment and find it generally useful (along with this whole answer, which I also upvoted), I really doubt introducing this overhead having 32 bits of data would make sense. Just think of what overhead would it be in case of 64-bit address space ;-)

Comment: Sometimes simplicity matters more than performance. I generally do not start optimizing until proven - it's always easier to make readable program optimized than to make optimized program readable. And after all, I simply did not know that one could just omit the struct name to get the desired result ;-)

Comment: And I think one can go fancy with C++ templates to achieve the same result as my "property" class - modern C++ compilers do heavy optimization, I'm not even sure that they'll keep your "convinient" as the class baggage in the final object code.

Comment: Although even your lack of knowledge about anonymous member I find almost positive, since it boosts creativity, I disagree with your view of optimizations. You, indeed, don't have to *optimize* before you have to, but it is important to try to write optimal code from the very start. And yes, it may be possible to do it with no compiled overhead, but source code overhead also impacts performance. Programmer's performance and code maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily wrap that in a class and use get/set accessors.

Comment: this makes code equally "bloated" and is not better than using a union

Comment: It would allow you to implement something that's actually portable without breaking the interface, and I don't see how it'd be more bloated.

Comment: bloated in the sense i outlined in my question: i want to ommit the accessors (.words, .bytes in this case)

Comment: it would omit the accessors.

You cauld have a GetHighWord function directly in your class.

Comment: yes, but I was asking for a way to write something like var.lowWord = 0x66;

Answer (score 0):

Using a union for this is bad, because it is not portable w.r.t. endianness.

Use accessor functions and implement them with bit masks and shifts.

Comment: true, but how would you write one class which would work with both types of endianess?

Comment: Implement them with bit masks and shifts. That works independently of endianness.

Comment: yeah but youo still need to have #defines in order to differentiate between big / little endianess. I don't see why I couldn't also do this with a union

Comment: No, you don't need to differentiate between endiannesses!  For example, accessing the high 16 bits of a 32 bit int is always (n >> 16) & 0xffff.

Comment: The question is, though, whether it's correct to refer to the *most significant* word as a *high word* ;-) And that makes me doubt if you can talk about endianness breakage at all here. It depends on what do you expect it to return. Depending on that you may safely say that what *you* do breaks with different endianness.

Comment: I bow to your wisdom, starblue. That's a perfect argument you've made here.